# I hit a regex roadblock while exploring a dataset of exported WhatsApp chats

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataset, data-science

I'm creating a dataset of exported WhatsApp chats. To manipulate the data, I need to split each line of the chat log into `date`, `time`, `sender` and `message` (columns).

```
import pandas as pd
import re

column_names = ["date", "time", "sender", "message"]
data = pd.read_table("datasets/WhatsApp Chat with Makay.txt", sep="re.split(', |- |:', data2)", names = column_names)
data.head()
```

> Output: The entire line/string goes into the date column, while time, sender
> and message all return NaN values.

Here's exactly a sample of the string:

```
string: '04/10/2020, 12:34 - Sender: Alright. This is the "message", with multiple de-limiters.'
```

> Expected output: ['04/10/2020', '12:34', 'Sender', 'Alright. This is
> the "message", with multiple de-limiters.']

I have tried the following patterns:

```
re.split(', |-|:', string)

re.split('\d\d[- /.]\d\d[- /.]\d\d\d\d[- /.] *?|, *?|- *?|: ', string)

re.split('\d\d[- ./]\d\d[- ./]\d\d\d\d[- ./]|, |- |: ', string)
```

but they all failed. Other similarly tagged questions didn't seem to answer this specific one. I have also visited regex101 web app but couldn't find a solution. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using split, you might match all the different parts in 4 capture groups.

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}), (\d{2}:\d{2}) - ([^:]+):\s*(.+)
```

- `^` start of string
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` Capture **group 1** Match a date like format *(which you could make more specific)*
- `,`  Match literally
- `(\d{2}:\d{2})` Capture **group 2** Match a timelike format *(which you can also make more specific)*
- `-`  Match literally
- `([^:]+)` Capture **group 3** Match 1+ times any char except `:`
- `:\s*` match `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(.+)` Capture **group 4** match any char 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDmqSV/1/)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

column_names = ["date", "time", "sender", "message"]
with open('datasets/WhatsApp Chat with Makay.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    items = re.findall(
        r"^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}), (\d{2}:\d{2}) - ([^:]+):\s*(.+)",
        file.read(),
        re.MULTILINE
    )

    df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=column_names)
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

    print(df)
```

Output

```
         date   time  sender                                                     message
0  04/10/2020  12:34  Sender  Alright. This is the "message", with multiple de-limiters.
```

Comment: The matching pattern works beautifully when I tested it on a sample string. However, I got a "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." on line 7 when I tested it on the dataset.

Comment: @Sillette Can you try it with the updated code?

Comment: Hit another error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4096: character maps to <undefined>" on line 6, and I have no idea what that means

Comment: @Sillette and if you use `with open('datasets/WhatsApp Chat with Makay.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:`

Comment: Now it works and I'm super delighted. But it doesn't iterate through the entire dataset, only the first message.

Comment: @Sillette O my bad, I forgot re.MULTILINE as the pattern uses an anchor. See the updated code.

Comment: I abandoned this test project for weeks because I couldn't figure it out on my own. You've solved my dilema within an hour. First question asked, perfect response, really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Sillette You are welcome, glad I could help. Good luck!